# HTTParty options parameter not functioning properly

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm setting up an application which can make LastFM API Requests.
These are simple get requests and I'm using the HTTParty gem.

My function is as follows:

```
def get_albums
  self.class.base_uri "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/"
  options = {
    :user => "Gerard1992",
    :method => "user.gettopalbums", 
    :api_key => Constants::LASTFM_API_KEY, 
    :format => "json"
  }
  puts options.to_query
  self.class.get "/?#{options.to_query}", {} #options don't work
end
```

This piece of code that's shown above works. The get request returns a set of JSON. My problem is that this `/?#{options.to_query}` doesn't look that neat. And neither does the actual (now empty `{}`) options parameter. How do I get the HTTParty options parameter to work like it should?

This is what I've tried, but both cases failed:

```
self.class.get "/", options
self.class.get "/", options => options
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct option for query parameters in HTTParty is `:query`, so what you want is:

```
self.class.get "/", query: options
```

You can see all the available parameters in [the docs](http://rdoc.info/gems/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods).

Comment: I find this rather weird. I also switched from the HTTParty gem to the Rest-client gem, because HTTParty uses the 'self.class." which is not that neat. Thanks anyway for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Send :verify => false in options hash